# Redirect after completing an action with react-router-dom V5.+

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, screen, router

I'm having trouble with navigating between screen with react-router-dom. What I'm trying to do is that after completing an action I want to navigate to other screen. Sorry for the noob question but it's my first time working with react.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using hooks, use react-router doms useHistory hook https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks

for example:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using these commands

```js
this.props.history.push("/Home")// use this for class component 
props.history.push("/Home")// functional component  (and pass props to the component)
```

Example:

```js
function LoginComponent(props) {

  const handleClick=()=> {
    props.history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

and make sure you wrote Routes in the app.js

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";

        <Router>
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
        </Router>
```